# GPO Deploy Printer Based on User Attribute

Tags: group-policy, ldap, printer

I am trying to deploy printers based on the Office attribute in AD. If a user is assigned to the Richmond office they should get those printers. Please note this is NOT location based printing. I just want the appropriate printers automatically installed based on assigned office.

Currently I am working with item level targeting, and trying to use an LDAP filter to pull out the office. Here is the filter I am currently using. The samaccountname option was added by my helpdesk team, but it has not made a difference.

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Richmond\20Corporate)(samaccountname=%LogonUser%))
```

Comment: for what reason would you want to auto assign a printer to a person in a place they are not local to?  I'm trying to figure out your use case.

Comment: We have deployed VDI across all remote locations. Each site has a set of local printers. When a new user starts with the company they will be associated to a location. I want their desktop to auto-populate with the printers from that location. We do NOT use thinprint, instead mapping from our print server.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that my original query works just fine, the problem was the drivers. Though standard users have permission to install printer drivers these are not trusted by Windows. Manually installing the printer using Windows explorer gave me a prompt to install anyway. This prompt does not appear during the policy application.

I am going to do some research on how to force install drivers using group policy. If I don't find what I need I will create a new question. Thanks for the help.

UPDATE :

Installing the latest print drivers on the print server corrected the install errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the first category, user->person.

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Richmond\20Corporate))`

If it dont work I would try without a space in Richmont Corporate, to remove the **\20**.